# Permutation of rings in Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently doing this three part question and I have 2/3 of it finished, but there is this confusing part that I can't seem to make sense of.

Question:

If we have 4 different beads, how many braclets can we make if it can't be flipped and rotations resulting in similar results?

- 4!/4

If we are allowed to flip?

- 4!/4/2

Consider the size of all bracelets with distinct beads where the size of the bracelet is the number of beads. What is the counting sequence?

- I do not know what it means by counting sequence, can someone explain to me what it wants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the last part really should read as follows:

> Consider the set of all bracelets with distinct beads, where the size of the bracelet is the number of beads. What is the counting sequence?

Let $B_n$ be the number of distinct bracelets with $n$ distinct beads, and let $b_n=|B_n|$, the number of such bracelets. For example, in the first part you found that $b_4=\frac{4!}4=3!$, assuming that flipped bracelets are considered distinct, but rotated ones are not. The counting sequence for this class of bracelets is the sequence $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and you’re being asked to find a closed formula for $b_n$ in terms of $n$.